# Joining two SQL tables where external ID from table 1 appears twice in table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having issues joining two tables where one ID is used multiple times in another table.

Here  are the tables:

1st (groups_table):

| Group_ID | Group_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | First group |
| 2 | Second group |

2nd (transactions_table):

| Transaction_ID | External_Group_ID | Internal_Group_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

The output should look like below (group names to be added from table 1):

| Transaction_ID | External_Group | Internal_Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First group | Second group |
| 2 | Second group | First group |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to join to the `groups_table` twice to get the result that you want. Let set up your data first:

```
if object_id('groups_table') is not null
    drop table groups_table

CREATE TABLE groups_table
    ([Group_ID] int, [Group_name] varchar(12))
;
    
INSERT INTO groups_table
    ([Group_ID], [Group_name])
VALUES
    (1, 'First group'),
    (2, 'Second group')
;

if object_id('transactions_table') is not null
    drop table transactions_table


CREATE TABLE transactions_table
    ([Transaction_ID] int, [External_Group_ID] int, [Internal_Group_ID] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO transactions_table
    ([Transaction_ID], [External_Group_ID], [Internal_Group_ID])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2),
    (2, 2, 1)
;
```

Then when you query the tables you'll join to the `groups_table` twice:

```
select 
    tt.Transaction_ID,
    ExternalGroup = g1.Group_name,
    InternalGroup = g2.Group_name
from transactions_table tt
left join groups_table g1
    on tt.[External_Group_ID] = g1.Group_ID
left join groups_table g2
    on tt.[Internal_Group_ID] = g2.Group_ID
```

This should return the result (See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d20516/2/0)):

| Transaction_ID | ExternalGroup | InternalGroup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First group | Second group |
| 2 | Second group | First group |

Comment: Great, that works perfectly. I just had to change those two lines as follows:     
g1.Group_name as ExternalGroup,
g2.Group_name as InternalGroup